# Multi-class Classification Task with Input space size n x 1

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification

I am trying to create a model that predicts / classifies the response variable with an input space of size `n x 1`, which is essentially a single feature. To be more precise, I have to predict which class in among 0~9 (y) would it be according to a probability value (X).

Intuitively, I am thinking that y and X will have negative correlation. However, I cannot really think of a model that would perform well under the condition provided above since there is only one feature to consider when creating a model.

I have tried XGBoost and RandomForest, but I feel like I used those models mostly as blackboxes. Please do suggest a fine machine learning model to conduct such multi-class classification with input space of size `n x 1`. Thank you!

Comment: have you produced a plot of the data? is there even a need for machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

The method to use depends on the problem at hand.

- Is your data linearly separable? In the case of a single feature, this corresponds to all instances of a class being within a lower and an upper bound. If this is the case, then a simple model like logistic regression should do the trick.
- If your data is not linearly separable, then a decision tree could be enough. The optimization would take care of finding the optimal cuts in the values of the feature to split the data into the different classes.
- Another option for non-linearly separable data is to use an SVM with some kernel that makes your data linearly separable.

More complex methods are designed to capture patterns in the data when multiple features are available, and as such shouldn't be expected to perform well under these conditions.